# Creating .ipp files in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using C++ to do a homework assignment. I am using templates for my class, so I need all implementations of template methods to be in .ipp, not .cpp file (I can't write implementation in .h file as it is the assignment submission requirement)

Eclipse does not seem to support .ipp files without additional settings. There is not much information about .ipp files on the internet, I could not find anything helpful.
I defined a new file type in Eclipse preferences to be able to create an .ipp file. Now that I am trying to write my methods definitions in .ipp file, it keeps complaining that "member declaration is not found" even though I write #include *.ipp" at the end of my header file.

What could the problem?

Comment: What are *.ipp files?

Comment: The exact file extension of C++ files are not consistent industry-wide. Some people use `.h/.hh/.hpp/.hxx`. There's also `.cpp/.cc/.cxx`. And there are other file extensions used for other file types, but there's not much way to be certain about what a file extension means if it's not in the `.h/...` or `.cpp/...` set.

Comment: I am using templates, so method implementations need to be either in the .h file or in .ipp file. Since I have to submit .ipp file for my assignment, I am trying to figure out how to make it work on Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You have to register `.ipp` as C++ source file extension:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: C/C++ > File Types*** click ***New...***
2. Enter the pattern ***`*.ipp`*** and as type select ***C++ Source File***
3. Click ***OK***
4. Click ***Apply and Close***

Comment: I did that, but I first made it as c++ header file, now changed it to be a source file, and still the same, ughhhhh

Comment: Make sure you have a C++ project (in a C project C++ files are ignored) and to open it with the _C/C++ Editor_ (right-click an `*.ipp` file and choose _Open With > Other..._, select _C/C++ Editor_, check _Use it for all '*.ipp' files_ and click _OK_).